# d.ts file export module

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

I begin with Typescript and i try to create a new module but i have some problems.

I want to import a js file into my index.ts, so i know that I have to create a d.ts file in order to create and explain the function for typescript. Into my index.ts i put this :

```js
import Toto from "./toto";
```

And this is my d.ts file :

```js
declare module 'Toto' {

    function myfunction(callback : Function);

    export default myfunction;

}
```

But into my d.ts file i have this error :

> TS1128 : Declaration or Statement expected

I don't understand why because my test is very easy.

I use webpack to build the code, this is my webpack.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
    entry: "./index.ts",
    output: {
        path: "bundle/",
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions : [".ts", ".tsx", ".js"]
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: "ts-loader" }
        ]
    }
};
```

And my tsconfig.json

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target" : "es5"
  }
}
```

If you have any ideas :)

Regards

Comment: where is your `d.ts`file will be placed once finished?>

Comment: At the same place as index.ts

Comment: _I want to import a js file_ show the code for it

Comment: Toto it was just an example, i want to import this file : https://github.com/meetecho/janus-gateway/blob/master/html/janus.nojquery.js

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load .js files directly just set the "allowJS" flag in the compiler options. TS will then try to use type inference based on the JS.
[TS Compiler options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html)

So in you case just add the allowJS flag to the compiler options and skip the d.ts file.

Answer (score 0):

This set-up works for me

```
//toto.js
function myfunction(callback) {
    callback("42")
}    
exports.default=myfunction


//toto.d.ts
export default function myfunction(callback : Function);


//main.ts
import myfunc from './toto'    
myfunc((res) => console.log(res) )


//tsconfig.json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target" : "es5"
    }
 }
```

Running `node main.js` correctly logs 42

---

Alternatively using `allowJs`

- from the set-up above, remove the `toto.d.ts` definition file
- add `"allowJs":true` in tsconfig compilerOptions

---

=> The first solution requires the crafting of a definition file, but you benefit from typings when using `myfunc` in `main.ts`.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found my problem, my EDI (phpStorm) was too old and it compile the code in Typescript 1.4 whereas i was in Typescript 2.2.1...

Thanks for your feedback i don't know that i can use this option allowJs but for me it's not recommended because i want to document my code with typedoc and i need to create this d.ts file in order to do that.